# Making Heading Text Overlap its Bottom Border in a Box-like Fashion

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the HTML/CSS equivalent of the image attached. This specification has been provided to me in image form.

The text must be centralised and can be a dynamic width.

The border at the bottom must always stretch to the edges of the heading element.

The border must stop where the text starts and ends.

Any ideas which is the best way to achieve this?

As I do not have enough rep to post images yet, here is a link to it:

[Attachment Image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B30pLbbctznANExaeHhyUTlHamc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you go about it is going to have to depend on whether or not you need this to work on a printed background or not.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/gnEdA

## Flexbox

This will work on printed backgrounds no problem, but browser support is poor:  IE10, Opera, Chrome.  It does not require additional markup.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```
h1 {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  font-style: italic;
}

h1:before, h1:after {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  content: " ";
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1;
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

## White background

This should work for just about any browser you can think of.  However, it requires a solid background and additional markup.

```
h1 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 span {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, the second option is what I am looking for as the background colour will be known to me. Thank you.